Kiosk mode Ubuntu 20.04
I had developed a pyside6 GUI ,how can i make that as the single application running in my device (touch screen) as a kiosk mode in ubuntu 20.04(only this application should be visible to the user all the other things should be disabled)

I mean you just need to hide interface(panels and other). We use lubuntu on our projects and just hide bottom panel with next command:
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/lxqt-panel.desktop ~/

and the next one to hide notifications:
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/lxqt-notifications.desktop ~/

